# Do I need a design pattern here?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a rather theoretical question.

For example I have an class of objects - like Table. And this table could be colored with different colors - red, blue and yellow. If the table was not colored before, the result is clear. Otherwise the following rules are in play:

```
red + yellow --> orange
blue + yellow --> green
red + blue --> purple
red + blue + yellow --> brown
```

What is the nicest and the most elegant way to implement this? Is there any design patter for such a case? My variant may be too straightforward:

```
public class Table{

private boolean isRed;
private boolean isBlue;
private boolean isYellow;

     public String colorRed(){
         isRed = true;
         if (isBlue && isYellow) 
               return "brown";
         if (isBlue)
               return "purple";
         if (isYellow)
               return "orange";
         return "red";
     }
     //... the same for other colors
}
```

Comment: I would associate the colours to numerical constants, and do simple math instead of `if`s ^^

Comment: ^ I'd go a step forward, and associate the colors with powers of two. Then the result is a simple switch or map lookup on a numerical value that is composed of those powers of two.

Comment: @user2957954 Are you looking for a pattern specifically for this example or a general case which has similar `if-else` statements not necessarily concerned with colors. That said, why don't you have flags called `isBrown` or `isOrange` or `isPurple` as well? Just trying to understand the requirement here.

Comment: @CKing, I think I don't need flags for mixed colors. Does it help somehow?

Comment: @user2957954 What happens when `colorRed` is called? Does your table continue to stay *red* if say `isBlue` was true as well? Or does it turn to a new color? If it continues to stay *red*, does that method belong to the `Table` class since it doesn't change the color of the table.

Comment: @CKing, could you read java code or my english description please? when the table had been already blue, the result color should be purple.

Comment: @user2957954 I did see your code and I did read the English description. Your `colorXXX` methods are currently doing a set and get. This violates the single responsibility principle IMO. What you should do is have a `String tableColor` variable in `Table` to hold the current color. When `colorRed` is called, set this variable accordingly. Provide a `getTableColor` method to get the current color of the table. This way, you have one method that *sets* the color and one method that is used for *getting* the color instead of having a `setAndGet` style method that you have implemented right now.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine):
[image]

Suggested implementation:

```
interface IColorState {
        IColorState AddBlue();
        IColorState AddRed();
        IColorState AddYellow();
}

class BlueState: IColorState {
     public override AddBlue() {return new BlueState()}
     public override AddRed() {return new PurpleState()}
     public override AddYellow() {return new GreenState()}
}

class YellowState: IColorState {...}

class RedState: IColorState {...}

class PurpleState: IColorState {
     public override AddBlue() {return new PurpleState()}
     public override AddRed() {return new PurpleState()}
     public override AddYellow() {return new BrownState()}
}
```